# how to animate falling div from the top and rotate?

Tags: html, css

Hello guys i am trying to make animation like phone falling down from the top when it reach to the bottom it rotate and skew to make it seems that its 3d shape, but it seems that the animation that i made it keep flickering when it reach the 100% in keyframes, can anyone show me a trick, tips or example how i  can achieve this? thanks here's my code hope it help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
  <script defer src="brands.js"></script>
  <script defer src="solid.js"></script>
  <script defer src="fontawesome.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .phone{
            width: 600px;
            height: 1080px;
            background-color: black;
            border-radius: 9%;
            margin: 50% auto;
            position: relative;
            animation: bounce 2s ease-in-out forwards;
        }
        @keyframes bounce {
        0%   { transform: translateY(-500px); }
        50%  { transform: translateY(0); }
        70% { transform: translateY(-200px); }
        100%{
            transform: translateY(-50px) rotate(30deg) skew(5deg,347deg);;
        }
        }
        .inner-phone{
            width: 553px;
            height: 1039px;
            background-color: #f5f7fa;
            position: absolute;
            left: 9px;
            top: 14px;
            border-radius: 9%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .inner-phone:before{
            content: "";
            width: 200px;
            height: 10px;
            background-color: black;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 50px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin:auto;
            border-radius: 50px;
            z-index: 1;
        }       
        .inner-slider{
            width: 330px;
            height: 170px;
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 201px;
            margin-top: 30px;
            perspective: 1400px;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
            z-index: 10;
        }
        .circle{
          position: absolute;
          width: 150px;
          text-align: center;
          height: 150px;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          color: white;
          font-weight: bold;
          border-radius: 50%;
          cursor: pointer;
          transition: transform 400ms ease;     
          background-color: red;
          box-shadow: 0 13px 26px rgba(0,0,0, 0.3), 0 12px 6px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0px);
          transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }
        .circle label{
            line-height: 10px;
        }
        .icon{
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          margin-top: 44px;
          font-size: 30px;
        }
        .one {
          background: tomato;
          transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0px);
        }

        .two {
          background: yellowgreen;
          transform: translate3d(73%, 0, -450px);
        }

        .three {
          background: dodgerblue;
          transform: translate3d(148%, 0, -1045px);
        }

        .four {
          background: slateblue;
          transform: translate3d(-239%, 0, -1045px);
        }

        .five {
          background: violet;
          transform: translate3d(-110%, 0, -450px);
        }
        .inner-screen{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .chat-screen{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
        }
        .container-chat{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
        }
        .chat-item{
            min-width: 100%;
        }
        .ci1{
            background-color: tomato;
        }
        .ci2{
            background-color: yellowgreen;
        }
        .ci3{
            background-color: dodgerblue;
        }
        .ci4{
            background-color: slateblue;
        }
        .ci5{
            background-color: violet;
        }
        #wrapper {
          width: 100%;
          margin: 200px auto;
        }

        body {
          font-family: Arial;
          background: #fff;
        }

        .chat ul {
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px;
          list-style: none;
        }

        .message-left .message-time {
          display: block;
          font-size: 12px;
          text-align: left;
          padding-left: 30px;
          padding-top: 4px;
          color: #ccc;
          font-family: Courier;
        }

        .message-right .message-time {
          display: block;
          font-size: 12px;
          text-align: right;
          padding-right: 20px;
          padding-top: 4px;
          color: #ccc;
          font-family: Courier;
        }

        .message-left {
          text-align: left;
          margin-bottom: 16px;
        }

        .message-left .message-text {
          max-width: 80%;
          display: inline-block;
          background: #fff;
          padding: 15px;
          font-size: 14px;
          color: #999;
          border-radius: 30px;
          font-weight: 100;
          line-height: 1.5em;
        }

        .message-right {
          text-align: right;
          margin-bottom: 16px;
        }

        .message-right .message-text {
          line-height: 1.5em;
          display: inline-block;
          background: #5ca6fa;
          padding: 15px;
          font-size: 14px;
          color: #fff;
          border-radius: 30px;
          line-height: 1.5em;
          font-weight: 100;
          text-align: left;
        }

        .chat {
          padding: 20px;
        }

        .chat-container {
          height: 400px;
          overflow: scroll;
          overflow-y:hidden;
          overflow-x: hidden;
          padding-right: 16px;
        }

        .spinme-right {
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 15px 20px;
          font-size: 14px;
          border-radius: 30px;
          line-height: 1.25em;
          font-weight: 100;
          opacity: 0.2;
        }

        .spinme-left {
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 15px 20px;
          font-size: 14px;
          color: #ccc;
          border-radius: 30px;
          line-height: 1.25em;
          font-weight: 100;
          opacity: 0.2;
        }

        .spinner {
          margin: 0;
          width: 30px;
          text-align: center;
        }

        .spinner > div {
          width: 10px;
          height: 10px;
          border-radius: 100%;
          display: inline-block;
          -webkit-animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
          animation: sk-bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
          background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
        }
         
        .spinner .bounce1 {
          -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
          animation-delay: -0.32s;
        }

        .spinner .bounce2 {
          -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
          animation-delay: -0.16s;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
          0%,
          80%,
          100% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0)
          }
          40% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.0)
          }
        }

        @keyframes sk-bouncedelay {
          0%,
          80%,
          100% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
          }
          40% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
            transform: scale(1.0);
          }
        }
        .rich-message{
            width: 100%;
            height: 440px;
            background-size: 100%;
            background-position-x:0px;
            background-position-y:26px;
            margin-top: 80%;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="phone">
        <div class="inner-phone">
            <div class="inner-screen">
                <div class="chat-screen">
                    <div class="container-chat">
                        <div class="chat-item ci1">
                            <div id="wrapper">
                              <div class="chat">
                                <div class="chat-container">
                                  <div class="chat-listcontainer">

                                    <ul class="chat-message-list">
                                    </ul>

                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="chat-item ci2"> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="chat-item ci3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="chat-item ci4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="chat-item ci5">
                        </div>                                  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rich-message">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="phone-drop-shadow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="portal-phone">
        
    </div>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var dd = document.getElementsByClassName('circle');
    var chatMessages = [{
      name: "ms1",
      msg: "Who are you?",
      delay: 1000,
      align: "right",
      showTime: true,
      time: "19:58"
    },
    {
      name: "ms2",
      msg: "We are young team of entrepreneurs, developers, designers and visionaries. We are based in Berlin and started working on Freedactics in early 2015.",
      delay: 6000,
      align: "left",
      showTime: true,
      time: "19:58"
    },
    {
      name: "ms3",
      msg: "Could you describe Freedactics in one sentence?",
      delay: 3000,
      align: "right",
      showTime: true,
      time: "19:58"
    },
    {
      name: "ms4",
      msg: "Everything from lecture to exam in your pocket: Freedactics is a cloud-based platform build for students needs.",
      delay: 7000,
      align: "left",
      showTime: true,
      time: "19:58"
    },
    {
      name: "ms5",
      msg: "And the longer version?",
      delay: 3000,
      align: "right",
      showTime: true,
      time: "19:58"
    },
    {
      name: "ms6",
      msg: "As students we use to organize all our daily life around web and mobile technology, except the actual studying part. For learning we still use huge amounts of paper, books and heavy backpacks.",
      delay: 11000,
      align: "left",
      showTime: false,
      time: "19:58"
    },
    {
      name: "ms7",
      msg: "Why? Because there is no solution out there to help students or teachers to easily digitalize their learning processes and contents. We think that learning should be fast, simple and effective. A platform for studying should give people the option to learn at their own scope, with their own contents integrated.",
      delay: 10000,
      align: "left",
      showTime: false,
      time: "19:58"
    },
    {
      name: "ms8",
      msg: "This is why we developed Freedactics – a cloud-based solution tailored to students needs.",
      delay: 8000,
      align: "left",
      showTime: true,
      time: "19:58"
    },
    {
      name: "ms9",
      msg: "What makes you different from other learning platforms?",
      delay: 4000,
      align: "right",
      showTime: true,
      time: "19:58"
    },
    {
      name: "ms10",
      msg: "We understand the needs of individual student. We don’t focus so much on content publishing or learning management but on learning. At the same time we acknowledge the need to integrate different perspectives, such as flash cards, content and task management.",
      delay: 8000,
      align: "left",
      showTime: false,
      time: "19:58"
    },
    {
      name: "ms11",
      msg: "So we end up with a unique mix of focus on User Experience and thrive towards integration.",
      delay: 4000,
      align: "left",
      showTime: true,
      time: "19:58"
    },
    {
      name: "ms12",
      msg: "What is your vision for the future?",
      delay: 4000,
      align: "right",
      showTime: true,
      time: "19:58"
    },
    {
      name: "ms14",
      msg: "We are releasing an App right now. But that’s only breaking ground. In fact, we have something much bigger in mind: a universe of education! Our vision is to connect people, connect tools and power learning through intelligent systems.",
      delay: 9000,
      align: "left",
      showTime: true,
      time: "19:58"
    },
    {
      name: "ms15",
      msg: "Thanks! Something you want to add?",
      delay: 3000,
      align: "left",
      showTime: true,
      time: "19:58"
    },
    {
      name: "ms16",
      msg: "You are welcome! Yes, check out freedactics.com!",
      delay: 9000,
      align: "left",
      showTime: true,
      time: "19:58"
    }
                       ];
    var chatDelay = 0;

    function onRowAdded() {
      $('.chat-container').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.chat-container').prop('scrollHeight')
      });
    };
    $.each(chatMessages, function(index, obj) {
      chatDelay = chatDelay + 4000;
      chatDelay2 = chatDelay + obj.delay;
      chatDelay3 = chatDelay2 + 10;
      scrollDelay = chatDelay;
      chatTimeString = " ";
      msgname = "." + obj.name;
      msginner = ".messageinner-" + obj.name;
      spinner = ".sp-" + obj.name;
      if (obj.showTime == true) {
        chatTimeString = "<span class='message-time'>" + obj.time + "</span>";
      }
      $(".chat-message-list").append("<li class='message-" + obj.align + " " + obj.name + "' hidden><div class='sp-" + obj.name + "'><span class='spinme-" + obj.align + "'><div class='spinner'><div class='bounce1'></div><div class='bounce2'></div><div class='bounce3'></div></div></span></div><div class='messageinner-" + obj.name + "' hidden><span class='message-text'>" + obj.msg + "</span>" + chatTimeString + "</div></li>");
      $(msgname).delay(chatDelay).fadeIn();
      $(spinner).delay(chatDelay2).hide(1);
      $(msginner).delay(chatDelay3).fadeIn();
      setTimeout(onRowAdded, chatDelay);
      setTimeout(onRowAdded, chatDelay3);
      chatDelay = chatDelay3;
    });    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: replace tranform with this in your 100% keyframe-  transform-origin:100% 50;
             transform: translateY(-100px) rotate(30deg) skew(-10deg,-10deg);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your are trying to achieve is easier to implement with the css [rotate3d](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate3d%28%29) function.

You can mimic the rotation of an inclined element by just using `transform: rotate3d(-0.3, 1, 0, 390deg)`:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 240px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transform: rotate3d(-0.3, 1, 0, 30deg);
  animation: rotate 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(-0.3, 1, 0, 390deg); /* 405 = 360 + 45 */
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

So in your case, just add the falling animation and you have this impression of a phone that falls on the ground:

```css
body {
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 240px;
  width: 150px;
  top: 0%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transform: rotate3d(-0.3, 1, 0, 30deg);
  animation: fall 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fall {
  25% {
    top: calc(100% - 240px);
    transform: rotate3d(-0.3, 1, 0, 45deg);
  }
  100% {
    top: calc(100% - 240px);
    transform: rotate3d(-0.3, 1, 0, 405deg);
    /* 405 = 360 + 45 */
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    A text...
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify all the animation values in all keyframes, skipping the rotation and skew values in other keyframes is what's causing the jank.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
  <script defer src="brands.js"></script>
  <script defer src="solid.js"></script>
  <script defer src="fontawesome.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .phone{
            width: 600px;
            height: 1080px;
            background-color: black;
            border-radius: 9%;
            margin: 50% auto;
            position: relative;
            animation: bounce 2s ease-in-out forwards;
        }

        @keyframes bounce {
          0% { transform: translateY(-500px) rotate(0) skew(0, 0); }
          50% { transform: translateY(0) rotate(0) skew(0, 0); }
          70% { transform: translateY(-200px) rotate(0) skew(0, 0); }
          100% {
            transform: translateY(-50px) rotate(30deg) skew(5deg, 347deg);
          }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="phone">
        <div class="inner-phone">
            <div class="inner-screen">
                <div class="chat-screen">
                    <div class="container-chat">
                        <div class="chat-item ci1">
                            <div id="wrapper">
                              <div class="chat">
                                <div class="chat-container">
                                  <div class="chat-listcontainer">

                                    <ul class="chat-message-list">
                                    </ul>

                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="chat-item ci2"> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="chat-item ci3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="chat-item ci4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="chat-item ci5">
                        </div>                                  
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rich-message">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="phone-drop-shadow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="portal-phone">
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```